# Azure Backup VM with files and MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup, azure

I have an Azure virtual machine that I use to run my java web applications. These web applications make files in the filesystem and are constantly updating the MySQL database I have on the virtual machine.

My question is, how does Azure virtual machine backups work? Would all I need to do be to backup the VM to Azure backup and it would backup a snapshot of the database and the files, so that way I can always simply restore this backup?

Or should I keep a separate MySQL and files backup location, and if so where?

Update:
I ended up using the following application connected to my dropbox account. Works very well. http://mysqlbackupftp.com

Comment: Are you just looking for an answer telling you whether Azure virtual machines backups can take an atomic snapshot of a running system?

Comment: What my main question is would the Azure backup service be enough for MySQL and my files to be safe? Or do I need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Backup makes the process very easy by simply restoring the entire VM for you. You can either replace or create a new VM based on the last backup job. The problem with Azure Backup is the limit of 1 job per day. For most scenarios, this RPO is not good enough.

In parallel, attach new data disks to the MySQL VM and create scripts to backup  the database at different times of the day (cron).

**Cronjob for automatic DB backup to date prefixed file**:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123189/cronjob-for-automatic-db-backup-to-date-prefixed-file

Comment: Thank you but I'm using a windows vm, is it about the same process?

Comment: yes. basically the same idea, but using task scheduler instead of cron. mysqldump works the same on windows or linux.